# JSF2 URL GET parameter

Tags: java, url, jsf-2

It's easily possible with JSF2 to process GET requests with this annotations:

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}"/>
  <f:viewParam name="name" value="#{bean.name}"/>
  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

and the init method in my bean:

```
public void init(ComponentSystemEvent e) throws AbortProcessingException {...}
```

This can be accessed with something like `test.jsf?id=8012&name=name`. Is it possible to use it like the `@PathParam` in REST and write the URL like `test/8012/name`?

PS: I know there is a term for this, but I cannot remember ....

Comment: RESTful URLs, Friendly URLs, Pretty URLs .. PrettyFaces!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is by using [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/). You'll make a `pretty-config.xml` file that will look like this:

```
<url-mapping id="test">
  <pattern value="/test/#{id}/#{name}"/>
  <view-id value="/faces/test.jsf"/>
</url-mapping>
```

Really, it's dead simple. PF will inject path parameters into your managed beans and will even call an action afterwards if you like. I love it. :) [The official documentation](http://ocpsoft.com/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.0/en-US/html/GettingStarted.html#getstarted.webxml) is probably everything you need.